# How do I find the x-coordinate of the point on the functions hat is closest to the origin?

Tags: calculus

For the function $f(x) = \frac{4}{\sqrt x}$, which of the following would be the x-coordinate that is closest to the origin?

(A) 1

(B) 2

(C) $\sqrt 2$

(D) $2 \sqrt 2$

(E) $\sqrt[3]2$

Answer (score 1):

the distance is given by $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ and we can plug in $$y=f(x)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{x}}$$ and we have
$$h(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{16}{x}}$$